# in asp.net c# how to get the value of dynamically created controls after clicking submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page I have a panel(generic panel). This one is populate by several panels build dynamically. Each inside panel contains one label `(id = "lbl"+ i.ToString())`, one photo `(id = "img"+ i.ToString())` and one button submit `("btn" + i.ToString())` created dynamically and populate with sql data. When the submit button is clicked, I would like to display the name in the label in an update panel beside the generic panel. How can I do that? Is somebody have a solution? Thanks a lot for your help
***My aspx file***

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Generic" runat="server" Style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px;">
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="page-header">
                        Vente à emporter
                        <small>Restaurant</small>
                    </h2>

                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Vos Informations
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Votre commande
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <i class="fa fa-file"></i> Valider
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-around;margin-bottom:30px">
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Entree" width="150px" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Entrées" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Plat" width="150px" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Plats" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_dessert" width="150px" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Desserts" />
                <asp:Button ID="btn_boisson" width="150px" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Boissons" />
            </div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
            <div>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Entree" class="col-md-9" runat="server" style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" class="col-md-3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="panel panel-danger">
                            <div class="panel-heading">A emporter</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1"  class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Valider votre commande" style="justify-content:center"/>
                                <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;margin-top:20px"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

***My code behind***

```
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["restau"].ConnectionString;

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //if (!IsPostBack)
                //{
                    BindEntree();
                //}
            }

            protected void BindEntree()
            {
                SqlConnection con = null;
                SqlCommand cmd = null;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                string strQuery = "select * from recette_restau2 where type_plat='entree' and prix_vente is not null and nbre_pers is not null and picture is not null";

                con = new SqlConnection(constr);

                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);

                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(ds, "TableEntree");
                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows.Count; i++)
                    { 
                        byte[] barrImg = (byte[])ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows[i][15];

                        if (barrImg != null && barrImg.Length > 0)
                        {
                            int identree = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows[i][0]);

                            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(barrImg, 0, barrImg.Length);

                            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divEntree = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                            divEntree.Attributes.Add("class", "panel panel-body");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("Border", "1px solid  #C7CAC9");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("BorderColor", "red");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("width", "350px");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("height", "350px");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("margin-right", "20px");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "20px");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("display", "flex");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("flex-direction", "column");
                            divEntree.Style.Add("justify-content", "space-between");

                            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divInfo = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");

                            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divTitrePrix = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                            divTitrePrix.Style.Add("display", "flex");
                            divTitrePrix.Style.Add("justify-content", "space-between");




                            Label lblTitre = new Label();
                            lblTitre.ID = "lblTitre" + i.ToString();
                            lblTitre.Style.Add("font-size", "1.5em");
                            lblTitre.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "10px");
                            lblTitre.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows[i][2]);

                            //Label lblObserv = new Label();
                            //lblObserv.ID = "lblObserv" + i.ToString();
                            //lblObserv.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows[i][16]);

                            TextBox lblPrix = new TextBox();
                            lblPrix.ID = "lblPrix" + i.ToString();
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("font-size", "1.1em");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "10px");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("height", "30px");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("width", "70px");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("color", "white");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("justify-content", "center");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("align-items", "center");
                            lblPrix.Style.Add("text-align", "center");
                            lblPrix.Attributes.Add("ReadOnly", "true");
                            lblPrix.Attributes.Add("enabled", "false");



                            lblPrix.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows[i][4] + " €");

                            Image ImageEntree = new Image();
                            ImageEntree.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
                            ImageEntree.Style.Add("width", "50%");
                            ImageEntree.Style.Add("height", "50%");
                            ImageEntree.Style.Add("margin-right", "10px");



                            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divChoix = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                            divChoix.Style.Add("display", "flex");
                            divChoix.Style.Add("justify-content", "center");
                            divChoix.Style.Add("align-items", "center");



                            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divBtnMinusPlus = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                            divBtnMinusPlus.Attributes.Add("class", "input-group");
                            divBtnMinusPlus.Style.Add("margin-right", "10px");

                            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                            img1.ID = "img1" + i.ToString();
                            img1.Attributes.Add("width", "15px");
                            img1.Attributes.Add("height", "15px");
                            img1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "img1_Click");
                            img1.ImageUrl = "Content/images/moins_rond.png";

                            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img2 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                            img2.ID = "img2" + i.ToString();
                            img2.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "img2_Click");
                            img2.ImageUrl = "Content/images/plus_rond.png";
                            img2.Attributes.Add("width", "15px");
                            img2.Attributes.Add("height", "15px");
                            
                            TextBox txtBoxNbre = new TextBox();
                            txtBoxNbre.ID = "txtBoxNbre" + i.ToString();
                            txtBoxNbre.Style.Add("width", "50px");
                            txtBoxNbre.Style.Add("text-align", "center");

                            AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDownExtender numericExtender = new AjaxControlToolkit.NumericUpDownExtender();
                            numericExtender.ID = "numericExtender" + i.ToString();
                            numericExtender.Width = 80;
                            numericExtender.Minimum = 1;
                            numericExtender.Maximum = 20;
                            numericExtender.TargetButtonUpID = "img2" + i.ToString();
                            numericExtender.TargetButtonDownID = "img1" + i.ToString();
                            numericExtender.TargetControlID = "txtBoxNbre" + i.ToString();




                            divBtnMinusPlus.Controls.Add(img1);
                            divBtnMinusPlus.Controls.Add(txtBoxNbre);
                            divBtnMinusPlus.Controls.Add(img2);
                            divBtnMinusPlus.Controls.Add(numericExtender);
                            
                            Button btnPrix = new Button();
                            btnPrix.ID = "btnPrix" + i.ToString();
                            //btnPrix.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn btn-danger hvr-icon-forward");
                            btnPrix.CssClass = "btn btn-danger hvr-icon-forward";
                            btnPrix.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                            btnPrix.Text = "Choisir";
                            btnPrix.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnPrix_Click);
                            //btnPrix.CommandArgument = "<%# Eval('id_recette') %>";

                            HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
                            hf.ID = "hf" +i.ToString();
                            hf.Value = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["TableEntree"].Rows[i][0]);



                            divTitrePrix.Controls.Add(lblTitre);
                            divTitrePrix.Controls.Add(lblPrix);




                            divInfo.Controls.Add(divTitrePrix);
                            //divInfo.Controls.Add(lblObserv);

                            divEntree.Controls.Add(divInfo);
                            divEntree.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

                            divChoix.Controls.Add(ImageEntree);

                            divChoix.Controls.Add(divBtnMinusPlus);

                            divEntree.Controls.Add(divChoix);

                            divEntree.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

                            divEntree.Controls.Add(btnPrix);

                            divEntree.Controls.Add(hf);




                            Panel_Entree.Controls.Add(divEntree);
                protected void btnPrix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
                                        try
                {//string s = (sender as Button).Text;
                    Button btn = (Button)sender;

                    string id = btn.CommandArgument;

                    Label1.Text = id;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label2.Text = ex.Message.ToString();

                }
                }
```

Comment: show us some code man! show what you've tried!

Comment: Are the controls you are creating Serverside controls i.e. asp:Labe...l or html controls i.e. <label...?

Comment: Of course. Sorry. Now you have my codes

Comment: DaniDev, both. I just posted my code. Thanks for your fast reply

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
 {
   Label myLabel = new Label();

   // Set the label's Text and ID properties.
   myLabel.Text = "Label" + i.ToString();
   myLabel.ID = "Label" + i.ToString();
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
   // Add a spacer in the form of an HTML <br /> element.
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
 }
```

it create dynamic labels with ids label1,label2 & so on

if you want to create dynamic button and its click so

```
 Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "btnSubmit";
btn.Text = "Submit";
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
this.Controls.Add(btn);
```

You will need event handler btnSubmit_Click to add click event to the button

hope this will help

Comment: Thanks Shayan. But when I click the submit button how can I get the label content in order to display it in my panel beside ?

Comment: well you need to code like  

`var allLabels = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label >().Concat(panle1.Controls.OfType<Label >());
foreach (Label label in allLabels )
{
    value+= label .ID + ": " + label .Text + "\\n";
}`

Comment: Thanks again Shayan. My point is, when all the divEntree are created, I would like when the user click the submit button to display all the content in my update panel

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your intention but I think this will do what you ask.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindEntree();
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
            }

        }
```

* you will have to eliminate the text value of your label:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Bear in mind there are several ways of doing this and this is rather crude but it will give you an idea how the postback works with update panels..

Comment: Thanks for your reply DaniDev. I certainly explain what I want very badly. In fact, I create multiple div (divEntree) in the panel depending on my sql server value. Each divEntree owns its submit button. I would like when the user clicks on it to display the content of the divEntree in a update panel placed beside my panel. I don't know how to do so because I can't get the id value of the sql row displayed in the divEntree

Comment: OK, Getting the idea but still not completely clear. I only see one update panel. you want each dynamically generated button to display the contents of what control (textbox)? onto what control (label)?

Comment: lol. Sorry for my english. The user can choose what he wants to display in the update panel. For instance, the page display 10 divEntree. He chooses 2 of them and display the content of them, by pressing each submit button, in the update panel. In the update panel you will have the photo and the name of his choice

Comment: OK vitruve, I now understand what you are trying to do. I tried to come up with a solution given your current set-up. However there are numerous issues to overcome namely 1.persisting the view state of your Items and  2. being able to dynamically make a each button an AsyncPostBackTrigger.
What you should do is have a static asp data control on your form such as a grid or repeater and dynamically add rows to that. Then you can iterate through the items during data bind and add a button to each row.
If you are new to asp.net

Comment: Thank you VERY much DaniDev. Yes I'm a newby with asp.net. I waiting forward you. Thanks again

Comment: Look at :
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70
then
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386452.aspx
and then
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/556204/Howplustopluscreateplusdataplustriggerplusforplusd